# Swift Ceil Print

Tags: ios, swift

Why is it that when I print:

```
print((buildingConstants.jitterClickConstantCost * 11)/10)
```

with `buildingConstants.jitterClickConstantCost = 1` I get

```
> 1
```

(which is expected)

But if I print

```
print(ceil(Double((buildingConstants.jitterClickConstantCost * 11)/10)))
```

(which you would assume would produce 2), produces:

```
> 0
```

Comment: the problem is that you do the calculation with integers and you lost the fragments before you even have a change to round; so, I'd try this, being sure the variable is double (or some kinda floating) as well: `debugPrint(ceil((Double(buildingConstants.jitterClickConstantCost) * 11.0)/10.0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dividing by 10 the compiler is inferring the 10 to be an Int, so you will get an answer returned as an Int. If you divide by 10.0 it will work as desired. The following gave the output of 2.0 using a Swift playground

```
    let x = Double((1 * 11)/10.0)
    print(ceil(x))
```